# knockout - issue when freezing header and columns

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-plugins, html-table

I am using following `table` with knockout bindings:

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="GridView1">
    <tr class="container-table" id="trHeaders">
        <!-- ko foreach: ColumnNames-->
        <!-- ko if: $data.FieldName == 'S.No.' -->
        <th class="td-border-left table-sr-no">
            <a style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="text: $data.DisplayName"></a>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </th>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $data.FieldName != 'S.No.' -->
        <th>
            <a style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="text: $data.DisplayName, click: function(data, event, index){$root.headerClick(data, event, $data.DisplayName)}"></a>
            <div class="both"></div>
        </th>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <th class="td-border-right">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- ko foreach: SResumeListingData -->
    <tr class="sticky-td">
        <!-- ko foreach: $parent.ColumnNames -->
        <!-- ko if: $data.FieldName == 'S.No.' -->
        <td data-bind="attr:{ class: $root.SetPackageExpireCss($parent.expiryflag) }">
            <span data-bind="text: $parent[$data.DisplayName]"></span>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $data.FieldName == 'ID' -->
        <td>
            <a data-bind="text: $parent[$data.DisplayName], attr: { href:  $root.SetViewResumeURL($parent.Pk_Id) }" target="_blank"></a>
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $data.FieldName == 'FullName' -->
        <td>
            <!-- ko if: $root.CheckIfSummaryColumnExists($parent) -->
            <div class="tooltip">
                <div class="user-name" data-bind="text: $parent[$data.DisplayName]"></div>
                <div class="name-bg">
                    <div class="name-title">Background </div>
                    <div class="user-bg">
                        <img src="../Content/images/name-user.png">
                        <div class="user-title"><!-- ko text: $parent[$data.DisplayName] --><!-- /ko --><span data-bind="text: $parent['PopupDesignation']"></span></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="content" data-bind="text: $parent['PopupSummary']"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: $root.CheckIfSummaryColumnExists($parent) -->
            <!-- ko text: $parent[$data.DisplayName] --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $data.FieldName != 'S.No.' && $data.FieldName != 'ID' && $data.FieldName != 'FullName' && $data.FieldName != 'Domain' && $data.FieldName != 'SubDomain' && $data.FieldName != 'Function' && $data.FieldName != 'SubFunction' -->
        <!-- ko if: $data.CanRequestForInfo -->
        <td>
            <!-- ko if: $parent[$data.DisplayName] == 'RequestForInfo' -->
            <div class="tooltip">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="email-error" data-bind="click: function(data, event, resumeId, fieldName, displayName){ $root.getRequestInfo(data, event, $parent.Pk_Id, $data.FieldName, $data.DisplayName)}"></a>
                <span class="tooltip-span" data-bind="text: $root.SetRequestForTooltip($data.DisplayName)"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: $parent[$data.DisplayName] == 'RequestInProcess' -->
            <div class="tooltip">
                <a href="javascript:;" class="email-process"></a>
                <span class="tooltip-span" data-bind="text: $root.SetRequestInProcessTooltip($data.DisplayName)"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: $parent[$data.DisplayName] != 'RequestForInfo' && $parent[$data.DisplayName] != 'RequestInProcess' -->
            <span data-bind="text: $parent[$data.DisplayName]"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: $data.CanRequestForInfo -->
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: $parent[$data.DisplayName]"></span>
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: $data.FieldName == 'Domain' || $data.FieldName == 'SubDomain' || $data.FieldName == 'Function' || $data.FieldName == 'SubFunction' -->
        <td>
            <span class="domain-tag" data-bind="click: function(resumeId){ $root.getTaggingInfo($parent.Pk_Id)}"></span>
            <!-- ko text: $parent[$data.DisplayName] --><!-- /ko -->
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <td class="td-border-right">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

I am using [this](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/) `jQuery` plugin to freeze the columns using the following code:

```
$('#GridView1').gridviewScroll({
                width: "99.99%",
                height: 300,
                railcolor: "#F0F0F0",
                barcolor: "#CDCDCD",
                barhovercolor: "#606060",
                bgcolor: "#F0F0F0",
                freezesize: 3,
                arrowsize: 0,
                varrowtopimg: "freez/arrowvt.png",
                varrowbottomimg: "freez/arrowvb.png",
                harrowleftimg: "freez/arrowhl.png",
                harrowrightimg: "freez/arrowhr.png",
                headerrowcount: 1,
                railsize: 20,
                barsize: 4
            });
```

The columns which are visible and the order of column is configured by user for which I am using `ColumnNames` observable array. The problem I am facing is after applying the freezing code the table is getting separated into separate `div's` which is causing the header sort function `headerClick` to not to work in the freezed part. Whenever user sorts the column, I have to get the sorted data from db and bind again in the table. Since the `table` is already separated into `divs` on page load, only the un freezed part of the grid is getting updated. So is there any other plugin which I can use with the `knockout` bindings I am using above? Is there anyway to implement `header` and `column` freezing without using any `jQuery` plugins?

I mainly want to implement header and column freezing without disturbing the knockout binding logic I have written above.

Comment: According to demo page, you can enable and disable the freezing plugin. So I would create a custom ko model binder for this plugin, which has options such as frozen columns and isEnabled observable flag. So on headerClick you set isEnabled to false, which returns table to it's initial state, then update your data and in successful callback set isEnabled back to true, which freezes columns again.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin I have written some functions in my knockout view model which are called when some item inside the `td` is clicked and this doesn't require the table to be regenerated again. These functions are not working in the freezed part of the grid as the entire table is split into multiple `div` elements by the plugin. Can you please tell any other useful plugin to implement column and header freeze which works well with knockout bindings?

Comment: Well, this is tough one. Since plugin changes the markup, you should reapply bindings each time after that. Have you tried that: `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, GridView1)` after running plugin?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin yes I have tried that and result is still the same. I think the problem here is that `table` is split into multiple `div` elements which is causing the ko bindings to not work in freezed part. Any other way to implement this? For example maintaining two arrays, one for freezed part and the second for unfreezed part and applying css for the scrolls...