# freeze x number of columns and header using knockout

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-plugins

I am using `knockout` to bind data in a `table` element using an observable array which will contain a `JSON` object. I need to freeze x number of columns and freeze the header and add scroll for the rest of the elements. Since most of the jQuery plugins will split the `table` elements into multiple `div` elements, the `ko bindings` does not seem to work properly as I have posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053936/knockout-issue-when-freezing-header-and-columns) question. Is there any other `plugin` which will work properly with `knockout` bindings to freeze header and columns or is there any other way to implement this? For example maintaining two observable arrays, one for freezed part and the second for unfreezed part and applying css for the scrolls.

Is there any plugin which will split the `table` element into multiple `table` elements instead of multiple `div` elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you go down the path of writing your own, I would suggest that you figure out how you would accomplish this using HTML then work backwards.  Once you have it figured out in html, it should then be a matter of applying knockout and javascript to achieve the desired results.